# Sequences (limit properties in $ \mathbb{R}$)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Prove the following affirmation: Let $ k \in \mathbb{N}$  and $a>0$. If $a < x_n < n^k , \forall n$, then $ \lim x_n^{1/n} = 1$

I already proved that:
I) If $a>0$ then $\lim a^n =1$ and $ \lim n^{1/n} = 1$ (remember, I am talking about sequences, so my n is natural). So, clearly, I want to use the squeeze theorem to prove the affirmation.

Since $$ n^{k/n} = \underbrace{n^{1/n}n^{1/n}\cdots n^{1/n}}_{k\text{ times}} $$ (for k a natural number), I can prove that $\lim n^{k/n} = 1^k = 1$. But my doubt is: How can I show that $a < x_n < n^k \Rightarrow a^{1/n} < x_n^{1/n} < n^{k/n} $ (or something simiarly)? Is the function $x^{1/n} $ always monotonic for all n a natural number?

I don't think the objective of this demonstration is to do a long demonstration about this proposition (if it is true, I'm not sure) so I would like a hint of how to do it.

I don't know if this is the better way to prove the afirmattion, by the way.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes, it is monotonic. You should be able to prove it.

Comment: Yep, but I was thinking in an inconvenient proof. But it is now clear: For x>0, $x^{1/n} > 0$ and $ ( x^{1/(n+1)})' = \frac{1}{n+1}x^{1/n} > 0$, so the function $x^{1/n}$ is increasing (using induction)

Comment: There's a small mistake in the derivative, but that's indeed one way to do it, and with that result you've finished your proof very nicely.

Comment: haha, it was not a little mistake, it was a big one. by the way, I fixed it and could finish my proof (since my x is positive, it was not difficult) . Thanks